# I'm trying to create two content types at once in one form. One is a parent page the other a child page

Tags: entities, nodes

So I'm workoing on a story archive website and I've created several interations using the Book module in drupal. However while I like all the stuff book does by default I need to streamline the process of content creation and I'm no longer sure I can do that easily with book module.

I am right now trying to figure out how to create a way to create both the front page and the first child page of a story/book in the system, and create an easier way to add a chapter to a story and tell drupal what the chapter number is. If anyone has any advice on this I would appreciate it emensly.

Answer (score 0):

The [Inline entity form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module was built for pretty much that exact use case:

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
>
> The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>
> Existing entities can also be referenced.

Comment: YEa, I tried that but I'm ending up confused as I try to setup the reference.